# Android CalendarView split months

Tags: android, calendarview

Okay, here's a screenshot of what I have currently:
[image]

I'm sure it may be quite simple, but I'm having difficulties to find resources about what I'm trying to achieve. Essentially, I'm trying to get these two months evenly on the layout. Moreover, I'd like to increase the margin between the two months (as you can see that the 28th April is really too close to May 2016, either a bit more of more margin between them would be great or some sort of divider).

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/blurry_blue_wallpaper"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:dateTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:weekDayTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the CalendarView initialization:

```
public void initializeCalendar() {
        calendar = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        calendar.setShowWeekNumber(false);
        calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(2); // Monday
        calendar.setMinDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));
        calendar.setMaxDate(cal.getTimeInMillis());
}
```

I'd really appreciate any ideas/inputs with this matter. Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:
Not a major blocker and it has been replaced with a custom CalendarView. [This is the tutorial](https://www.toptal.com/android/android-customization-how-to-build-a-ui-component-that-does-what-you-want) I followed. Still, I'd be interested to know if the original question has a solution for what I was looking for.